# why hens determine the sex of the chick?

Tags: genetics, zoology, reproduction

So, I have an exercise where I have to correct the second part of the sentence. It goes like this:

> In hens, the sex of the chicken is determined by hen, because the hen is the heterogametic organism

And I really can't find the mistake, please help.
 Also, I'd like to know why hens determine the sex of the chick.

Comment: Outside of small eventual semantic issues about the notion of "determination", there is no mistake in this sentence.

Comment: Do you know what the sex determination system is like in birds? Do you know how the `XY` and `ZW` sex determination system work?